# Vbscript to run .Bat file with parameters and search for error in result txt file

Tags: vbscript

I am preparing vbscript to run bat files where bat file name contains version number, Script have to search for bat file with matching version name  . Once  Ran,The result Text file will be generated with same version number. I have to search for Text file with same version number and read the txt file for error or msg, if error found i want to display it. 
I know my requirement is little too much.
But I am finding little difficulty in debugging the code.I am stuck.
Can any one help me to resolve the issue.

Thank You

here is my script,
I am passing values for sql query from excel sheet.

```
    Dim Ver, Version_Number
Dim con
Dim rs
Set con=createobject("adodb.connection")
Set rs=Createobject("adodb.recordset")
Set PinXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set PinWB = PinXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\maspects\Trial.xls")                          '// Login and Enable Debug Window in application
Set PinWS = PinWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
varr = Cstr(PinWS.Cells(2,1).Value)
varr1 =  trim(varr)
usename =  Cstr(PinWS.Cells(2,2).Value)
UN = trim(usename)
password = Cstr(PinWS.Cells(2,3).Value)
PWD = trim(password)
IrisDB = Cstr(PinWS.Cells(2,4).Value)
DB = trim(IrisDB)
Site_Name = Cstr(PinWS.Cells(2,5).Value)
Site = trim(Site_Name)
con.open"provider=sqloledb.1;server=" & varr1 & ";uid=" & UN & ";pwd=" & PWD & ";database=" & DB &""
Wscript.sleep 1000*3
rs.Open  "select * from tblSettingsUnique where [Setting Name] like '%Revision%'" ,con 
Wscript.sleep 1000*2
Version_Number = rs.Fields("Setting Value")
Ver = Version_Number
 msgbox Ver
 Call Execute

 PinWB.Save
 PinWB.Close 
 PinXL.Quit 
 Wscript.Quit

 Function Execute
  If Ver < PinWS.Cells(2,6).Value = "True" Then   ' if Ver is less than Cell(2,6) value then application should come out of loop
    For i = Ver to PinWS.Cells(2,6).Value step 1
        msgbox i
       Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            For each f in Wshell.Getfolder("C:\maspects\DB_script").Files
                BatFile = instr(f.File , "4_0_"&i )
                WShell.Run ("CMD /K C:\maspects\DB_script\"&batFile &".bat" & Varr1 &" "& UN &" "& password )
                Call msg 
            Next            
    Next
   End If   
 End Function       


Function msg
      Set TxtObject = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For each ResFile in TxtObject.GetFolder("C:\maspects\DB_script").Files
             TargetFile = InStr(ResFile.File , "4_0_"&i )
            Set TxtFile = TxtObject.openTextFile("C:\maspects\DB_script\"&TargetFile, 1 ,true)
                Do until TxtFile.AtEndOfStream
                    For each F in TxtFile.Readline
                        if InStr (F,"msg" ) = "True" and InStr (F,"msg 207" )= "False" Then
                             msgbox "Error in:"&TargetFile 
                             React =Cint(Inputbox("Go through the Result file:"&TargetFile &"Enter '1' to Continue '0' to Quit"))
                             If React = "0" Then
                                   TextObject.Close
                                   Wscript.Quit
                             End if
                        End If
                    Next
                Loop    
          TextObject.Close                  
        Next         
End Function
```

Comment: Couple of suggestions - 1) When you use `WShell.Run` which will create a file, its best to wait for the command to finish. So use `WShell.Run <command>, 0, True` 2) Do a regex to find the error messages rather than going thru each line to speed up the process

Comment: Pankaj, Thank You for suggestion,

Comment: Pankaj, Thank You for suggestion, I will try to use first point. as for second Suggestion, I just need to go through all the result file to find a string with "msg" except "msg 207" , thats it.

Comment: Since you know the pattern of error message that is why line by line is inefficient. Regex will be faster.

Comment: I will try to use Regex, and Please see my code now I have mentioned the line where i am getting Syntax error. Any suggestion on this

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. `InStr(start, string being searched, string sought)` - e.g. `InStr(1, ResFile.File text (you need readall) , "4_0_" & i)

Comment: Pankaj, i think "start" is optional in Instr. So i omitted it, i have mentioned the string file and string sought in the script

Comment: I have updated my script, now i dont see any error. but script not entering the "Function Execute"